# MLE using product of parameters as constraint

Tags: r

Iwanted to find estimates of a distribution using two constraints. one is the product of three parameters is greater than 1 and other is one parameter of these parameters is 1.
I used different functions but they didn't work.
Kindly guide me.
hashmi

Comment: what have you done so far?? Show us the code

Comment: Hello Hashmi. You don't give much to go on here - there are several R functions that can optimise with constraints, but a fuller description of your problem is needed , or even better, an example. Could you please edit your question to show the function that you are trying to optimise, and the parameter constraints. And can you show the code that you tried, but didnt work. Cheers. [ps: worth a read](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example)